Grafana Tempo Error reading footer of parquet file: error in range read from s3 backend obj: XYZ/data.parquet: 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable
I’m encountering issues with my Tempo setup. While traces are successfully ingested into Tempo, I sporadically receive the following error when searching for traces in Grafana:
Query error
Error reading footer of parquet file: error in range read from S3 backend, bucket: tempo, objName: single-tenant/XYZ/data.parquet: 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable.

Additionally, I see these errors in the logs:
msg="error during compaction cycle" err="error shipping block to backend, blockID XYZ error completing block: error reading parquet file footer: error in range read from s3 backend, bucket: tempo, objName: single-tenant/XYZ/data.parquet: 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable".

I can confirm that the blocks are being written to my MinIO S3 backend, but the errors persist. I’m using the same S3 backend for my Mimir and Loki setups, where I don’t experience these issues.
My tempo setup has been scalable monolithic mode with 3 servers but I have also tried just simple monolithic mode. The tempo-config is very simple and uses default values for almost everything.
Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.
CONFIG:
server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  grpc_listen_port: 4310
  log_format: logfmt
  log_level: info

distributor:
  receivers:
    otlp:
      protocols:
        grpc:
          endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317
        http:
          endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4318
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: memberlist
    instance_interface_names:
      - ens160
      - lo

compactor:
  compaction:
    block_retention: 1h
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: memberlist
    instance_interface_names:
      - ens160
      - lo

memberlist:
  abort_if_cluster_join_fails: false
  bind_port: 4311
  advertise_port: 4311
  cluster_label: ${CLUSTER_NAME}
  cluster_label_verification_disabled: false
  randomize_node_name: false
  join_members:
    - ${SERVER_1}:4311
    - ${SERVER_2}:4311
    - ${SERVER_3}:4311

metrics_generator:
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: memberlist
    instance_interface_names:
      - ens160
      - lo

storage:
  trace:
    backend: s3
    s3:
      access_key: MINIO_USER
      secret_key: MINIO_PW
      bucket: tempo
      endpoint: localhost:7000
      insecure: true
    wal:
      path: /tempo/storage/trace/wal

querier:
  frontend_worker:
    frontend_address: localhost:4310

overrides:
  defaults:
    ingestion:
      max_traces_per_user: 0
    metrics_generator:
      processors: ['service-graphs', 'span-metrics']

usage_report:
  reporting_enabled: false

auth_enabled: false
multitenancy_enabled: false

